# Javascript and JQuery "this" scope errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

A sample bit of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myinfo">info</div>
<input id="clickme" type="button" value="click here to display info"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Fighter() {
        this.name = "Kenny";    // fighters name
        this.hp = 10;           // fighters hp
        this.getHP = function() {
            return this.hp;
        }

        this.getName = function() {
            return this.name;
        }

        this.initUpdateButton = function(button_id) {
            $(button_id).click(function() {
                $("#myinfo").html("Name: "+this.getName()+"<br/>HP:"+this.getHP()); 
                // this.getName is undefined
            });
        }

    };

    var me = new Fighter();
    alert("Name: "+me.getName()+"<br/>HP:"+me.getHP()); // works properly
    me.initUpdateButton("#clickme"); // bind it to some ID
</script>
```

Simply put, given a JavaScript class with JQuery mixed in, I understand that on the callback for JQuery functions (i.e. `$.click()`), that `this` is referring to the object that was clicked and **Not** the Class or root function(). so `this.getName()` and `this.getHP()` don't work.

But what is the best way to get around this problem?

I saw some similar posts but they weren't of use to me so sorry if this is a repost and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it really useful to have getter methods when your properties are public ? :)

Comment: Right, my actual implementation is not as simple as the example I whipped up for SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.initUpdateButton = function(button_id) {
            var self = this;
            $(button_id).click(function() {
                $("#myinfo").html("Name: "+self.getName()+"<br/>HP:"+self.getHP()); 
            });
        }
```

Comment: oh wow. so simple. a definite sign that I should sleep a bit more before coding :-/ Thanks!